# Overriding cd builtin to source env settings, possible to use with autocd?

Tags: command-line, bash, source

I am currently overriding the builtin `cd` command to source an environment file based on the environment currently being built.

My main question pertains to how `cd` runs when I have `shopt -s autocd` enabled--relying on `autocd` to get to the specific directories, my `source` lines do not get executed. Where can I find out more about how `autocd` runs `cd` and why this only works while explicitly calling `cd`?

My `.bashrc` contains this for the "auto sourcing":

```
cd() {
  builtin cd "$@"

  if [[ `pwd` == '/home/ubuntu/deploys/staging' ]]; then
    echo "Sourcing ~/.appconfig/staging.env!";
    source /home/ubuntu/.appconfig/staging.env;
  fi

  if [[ `pwd` == '/home/ubuntu/deploys/demo' ]]; then
    echo "Sourcing ~/.appconfig/demo.env!"
    source /home/ubuntu/.appconfig/demo.env;
  fi

  if [[ `pwd` == '/home/ubuntu/deploys/prod' ]]; then
    echo "Sourcing ~/.appconfig/prod.env!"
    source /home/ubuntu/.appconfig/prod.env;
  fi

}
```

I know this is a bit dangerous and could have unintended consequences, but I can live with that for now. If there's a better solution to automatically sourcing an environment var list when `cd`ing into a dir, I'm all ears.

Comment: style/performance tip: use `$PWD` instead of `$(pwd)`

Comment: Apparently `autocd` does not use the shell to execute a `cd` function. It probably goes straight to the C code to change your directory. You might have to forget about a `cd` function and put your code into the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable if you need `autocd`

Comment: @glenn-jackman thanks, yeah I recall the `PROMPT_COMMAND` technique, had some issues with it for another reason so avoided it for this. will have to revisit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find where the internals of `autocd` are documented, I'm afraid you'll have to check the source code. However, as Glenn points out, if this is not executed when using `autocd`, then `autocd` is probably not using `cd`.

I can think of two workarounds. First, you can use `PROMPT_COMMAND` as Glenn suggested. Add this to your `.bashrc`:

```
sourcedir() {

  if [[ `pwd` == '/home/ubuntu/deploys/staging' ]]; then
    echo "Sourcing ~/.appconfig/staging.env!";
    source /home/ubuntu/.appconfig/staging.env;
  fi

  if [[ `pwd` == '/home/ubuntu/deploys/demo' ]]; then
    echo "Sourcing ~/.appconfig/demo.env!"
    source /home/ubuntu/.appconfig/demo.env;
  fi

  if [[ `pwd` == '/home/ubuntu/deploys/prod' ]]; then
    echo "Sourcing ~/.appconfig/prod.env!"
    source /home/ubuntu/.appconfig/prod.env;
  fi

}

PROMPT_COMMAND="sourcedir"
```

Now, each time you move into these directories, irrespective of how you got there, the files will be sourced. A major drawback of this approach is that the files will be sourced each time a prompt is shown, not only when you first move into the directory. You could avoid this by setting a variable in the sourced file and only sourcing if that variable is not set but this is really getting rather complex.

I would instead suggest you set up aliases for moving into each of the directories and sourcing the relevant files. Add these lines to your `~/.bashrc` (`source` is actually an alias for `.` but `.` is more portable):

```
alias staging="cd /home/ubuntu/deploys/staging && . /home/ubuntu/.appconfig/staging.env"
alias demo="cd /home/ubuntu/deploys/demo && . /home/ubuntu/.appconfig/demo.env"
alias prod="cd /home/ubuntu/deploys/prod && . /home/ubuntu/.appconfig/prod.env"
```

Now, you can run `staging` to move into the staging directory and source the relevant file. The same for each of the other two.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about the alias approach before, I think now I will actually convert to that as it's much cleaner and isolated.